# Python Tkinter "exportselection" doesnt work on windows machines

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

A tkinter textbox feature, `exportselection=False` doesn't work on Win10 machines.

I have 2 textboxes and I need to highlight both of them at the same time. I just found `exportselection=False` and that works on my Linux machine.

So far, I tried on 3 Linux machines, 2 Win10 machines and it seems it only works on Linux.

```
textBox = Text(midFrame, height=textArea_height, width=textArea_width, exportselection=False)
```

Why its not working on Win10?

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show your Python, `tkinter` and `tcl` versions (Win10)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. One line of code isn't enough, especially when you're specifically asking about the interaction between two widgets.